# Issue in Group_by_at & Group_by

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

Below is the data frame and the code that I would like to execute.
As shown below I would like to group_by `x` as well as by `color`.
`x` is a string and hence I have used the `group_by_at` function.

```r
df <- data.frame(
        color = c("Yellow", "Blue", "Green", "Red", "Magenta"),
        values = c(24, 24, 34, 45, 49),
        Quarter = c("Period1","Period2" , "Period3", "Period3", "Period1"),
        Market = c("Camden", "StreetA", "DansFireplace", "StreetA", "DansFireplace"))
    
list = c("Market", "Quarter")

df_all <- do.call(rbind, lapply(list, function(x) {
    df_l <- df %>% 
              group_by_at(x) %>% 
              group_by(color) %>%
              summarise(values = sum(values)) %>% 
              mutate(cut = x) %>% 
              data.frame()
    colnames(df_l)[colnames(df_l) == x] <- "Grouping"
    df_l
}))
```

The issue is that while this code is running it is not grouping by `x`. Only when I remove `group_by(color)` does it group by `x`.

My objective is to group by both `x` and `color`.

Comment: @joran Nope tried that, does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, include `color` and `x` in the same `group_by` statement:

```
df_all <- do.call(rbind, lapply(list, function(x){
  df_l= df %>% group_by_at(c(x, "color")) %>% 
    summarise(values = sum(values)) %>% 
    mutate(cut= x) %>% 
    data.frame()
  colnames(df_l)[colnames(df_l)==x] <- "Grouping"
  df_l
}))
```

This gives:

```
        Grouping   color values     cut
1         Camden  Yellow     24  Market
2  DansFireplace   Green     34  Market
3  DansFireplace Magenta     49  Market
4        StreetA    Blue     24  Market
5        StreetA     Red     45  Market
6        Period1 Magenta     49 Quarter
7        Period1  Yellow     24 Quarter
8        Period2    Blue     24 Quarter
9        Period3   Green     34 Quarter
10       Period3     Red     45 Quarter
```